# Unable to understand why and is not working

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to understand why *Python* is not getting into the loop and exiting with an error code.
On the same time `OR` condition works fine.

```py
def user_choice():
    
    choice=''
    within_range = False
    
    while choice.isdigit == False and within_range == False:
        choice=input('Enter valid selection (1-9): ')
        
        if choice.isdigit() == False:
            print('You entered non-digit value, please input digit')
            
        if choice.isdigit() == True:
            if int(choice) in range(0,10):
                within_range=True
            else:
                within_range=False
        
    return int(choice)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also another flaw in the following blocks of code:
(you should change the "and" with "or" to get a proper result, otherwise regardless of what integer you put in( not inside the range), it will return that!

```
def player_choice():

    choice=' '
    within_range = False
    
    while choice.isdigit() == False **or** within_range == False:
        choice=input('Enter valid selection (0, 1, 2): ')
        
        if choice.isdigit() == False:
            print('You entered non-digit value, please input digit(0, 1, 2)')
            
        if choice.isdigit() == True:
            if int(choice) in range(0,3):
                within_range=True
            else:
                within_range=False
    return int(choice)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in this line:

```
while choice.isdigit == False and within_range == False:
```

You are comparing function `str.isdigit` with boolean `False`
You should instead evaluate function `choice.isdigit()`

Full fixed version:

```
def user_choice():
    choice = ''
    within_range = False

    while choice.isdigit() == False and within_range == False:
        choice = input('Enter valid selection (1-9): ')

        if choice.isdigit() == False:
            print('You entered non-digit value, please input digit')

        if choice.isdigit() == True:
            if int(choice) in range(0, 10):
                within_range = True
            else:
                within_range = False

    return int(choice)
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. My bad, I forgot to put (). However, I am not able to understand why the developer put 'and' instead of 'or' in the code line "while choice.isdigit() == False and within_range == False:"

Comment: @ManishAmin because you need to make sure you that `choice` is a string with digits AND it is within the specified range. User input must fulfill both conditions. But to be honest, that line could be just `while within_range == False:`, because `within_range` will change into `True` only if `choice` is a digit.